# Laravel DB::transaction()

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some code and tried it in two ways. It's not working as expected and is not rolling back data

Error produce example is in git : https://github.com/Namvarii/laravel-db-transaction-error

```php
\DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $order = Order::create([
        // data
    ]);

    $order->notes()->create([
        // data and cause a fail
    ]);

    // No morph map defined for model [App\Models\Order].

    $order->transaction()->create([
        // data
    ]);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \DB::rollBack();
    return "error";
}

\DB::commit();

return "success";
```

And

```php
\DB::transaction(function() use ($offer, $request) {
    $buyer = auth()->user();

    $order = Order::create([
        // data
    ]);

    $order->notes()->create([
        // data
    ]);

    // throw error, "No morph map defined for model [App\Models\Order]" because not alias is defined.

    $order->transaction()->create([
        // data
    ]);
});

return "success";
```

In the two of them, a morph alias error occurs and the request fails with the message `No morph map defined for model [App\Models\Order]`, but I wonder why `Order::create([/* data */]);` is not rolled back and is stored in the database.

---

update: Default laravel DB engine is null and my DB using MyIsam. And problem is that. thanks for answer @P.K.Tharindu

Comment: I'm not sure why this code wouldn't rollback; it _should_ if you do `catch(Exception $ex) { DB::rollback(); }` or `DB::transaction(...)`, unless the error being triggered is not catchable. I have very little experience with Morphing logic in Laravel, but have you done any searching for the error and tried to fix it? There's plenty of results on Google for your error, which is "No morph map defined for model".

Comment: @TimLewis yes, i wonder and it's why i asked, catch is trigger and get in there, i checked `DB::rollback();` and it's just null, because nothing will returned, i tried it with another DB error like puting "aaa" column that not exist, it's same, it isn't rollback.

Comment: Hmm... What database driver are you using? Is it one that supports transactions? For example, I mainly use MySQL, and I've got plenty of instances of `DB::rollback()` and `DB::transaction()` in my Laravel projects, and I've never had any issues, unless the exception is not catchable.

Comment: MySql driver and MariaDB sql 10.6.5, laravel latest. me too never have same problem, let's change to MYSQL db and check that.

Comment: @TimLewis it's the same in mysql db.

Comment: Yeah, and that's expected as from a quick Google search, MariaDB should support transactions... I'm honestly not too sure at this point... I would still suggest you try to solve your core issue too, which is providing a Morph Map (however that is done), but this definitely is not expected behaviour with Laravel's `DB` facade's interaction with your database layer.

Comment: @TimLewis your are true, i fixed morph problem, i just forgot that before test. but after test i saw that and i wonder in production, this behavior is gonna be serious problem, that's why i asked here. the error happen if manually i throw a error, too.

Comment: even i'm going give some time, and debug in laravel Illuminate\Database folder and find where is the problem. i hope to find it.

Comment: Yeah for sure! I will say there's nothing wrong with your question and you asking it here; it's an interesting problem and definitely shouldn't be happening, but honestly I'm stumped, and I unfortunately don't have a way to recreate your issue. I'd maybe consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77539288/edit) to include the `mysql` tag, and the complete error log from `storage/logs/laravel.log` when you catch this error (you might have to add `Log::error($ex)`), and maybe someone else will be able to recreate and help you debug this further.

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for advice. i created a git to produce error. if you have time, you can check. https://github.com/Namvarii/laravel-db-transaction-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a model and its relationships within a transaction, if an exception occurs, Laravel should automatically rollback the entire transaction, undoing any changes made within that transaction. **However, the underlying database engine has to support transactions for Laravel's transactional behavior to be effective.**

For instance, InnoDB, a storage engine commonly used with MySQL in Laravel applications, fully supports transactions and adheres to the ACID properties. InnoDB ensures that, in the event of an exception or error, any changes made within the transaction are reliably rolled back, preventing partial or inconsistent data from persisting in the database.

Conversely, certain storage engines, such as **MyISAM, lack native support for transactions**. In such cases, Laravel's transactional features may not function as expected.

Comment: You looked at repository, it's no matter what error I made, like throw exception manually or db column not found error, or..., anyway it don't rollback

Comment: I just tried running your repo and it works fine on my end with (MYSQL 8.0.27). I mean I see the errors, but nothing in the orders table. I also see the ID is still being incremented, which is expected when rolling back a transaction. So whatever it is, it's not in the code. Maybe you are using `MyISAM` engine instead of `InnoDB` in your database?

Comment: yes, my engine is MyISAM

Comment: Changed engine to InnoDB and problem is solved, what are problem? and please write it in answer to accept.

Comment: So that's the issue. MyISAM lacks native support for transactions. I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

you commit transaction after try cache,
Whether you are has error or not, transaction commit,

change code like this :

````php
  \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $order = Order::create([
                // data
            ]);

            $order->notes()->create([
                // data and cause a fail
            ]);
            // No morph map defined for model [App\Models\Order].

            $order->transaction()->create([
                // data
            ]);
            \DB::commit();
            return "success";

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \DB::rollBack();
            return "error";
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Having the `DB::commit()` inside the `try { ... }` or after the `catch() { ... }` block is equivalent; if no Exception is thrown, the code will exit the block and trigger any code after the `try / catch`. There's no reason this would work over the original solution.

Comment: @TimLewis you are true, it's not matter we have `DB::commit()` in try block or after that. @Ali-SSN anyway error occur in line `$order->notes()->create([]);` and don't reach there. i just wonder why $order creation not rolled back. i tried too many times and it's not understandable to me why...

Comment: @Mahdi , add catch for `ClassMorphViolationException`, but this class extend from `RuntimeException` and `RuntimeException` extend from `Exception` ‍♂️...

also check `catch (\Throwable $e) {`

Comment: @AliSSN i tried, that, i checked, it trigger to catch and execute `DB::rollback()`. i wonder what problem is...

Comment: @Mahdi me too...